# Why my flexbox isn't being in a row with v-for?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I created one component to be a box for other items and I'm using v-for to have four of these box in my page. In this way, they are only displayed in a column (and I'm not being able to change it), but for desktop I need two boxes per row and for mobile I need them displayed in a column. I already have a footer and a background but they're not using flexbox, so I just want to be able to change these boxes without having to change other componentes.

App.Vue code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Background />
    <div v-for="cliente in clientes" :key="cliente.id">
      <Steps :cliente="cliente"/>
    </div>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Steps from './components/Steps.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer2.vue'
import Background from './components/Background.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Steps,
    Background,
    Footer
  },
  data(){
      return{
          clientes:[
        {
            id: 1,
            name:"Detalhes da Partida"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name:"Jogadores"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name:"Evidência da Partida"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name:"Mensagem: (opcional)"
        }

      ]
      }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
}

</style>
```

Component code:

```
<template> 
    <section class="flex">
      <div>
        <p class="teste">{{cliente.id}}. {{cliente.name}}</p>
      </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Steps',
  props:{
      cliente: Object
  }
}
</script>

<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.teste{
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
  padding: .5em .5em 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 32em;
  height: 30em;
  background-color: #232323;
  margin: 1em auto;

}
.flex > div {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `flexbox` on the wrong container. You need to add class `flexbox` on the container that wraps the element that has `v-for` so that all the elements that is generated by `v-for` becomes `flex-items`.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-tree-engun?file=/src/App.vue)

**App.vue**

```
<section class="flex">
      <div v-for="cliente in this.clientes" :key="cliente.id">
        <Steps :cliente="cliente" />
      </div>
</section>
```

**Steps.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="teste">{{ cliente.id }}. {{ cliente.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

You need to add a media query to make 2 columns in medium and above devices and single column in mobile devices

**App.vue -> style**

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 32em;
  height: 30em;
  background-color: #232323;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.flex > div {
  flex: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex > div {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks! But now there’s another problem: the elements are stuck together and I can’t give a space between them.

Comment: That's a different problem. That's because of your CSS. You need to change it accordingly. I don't know the requirement.

Comment: Oh ok, but why does it breaks to columns when I try to change it's margin-right?

Comment: That's because of the `flex: 50%`. check now I've changed it accordingly...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-tree-engun?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: BTW if you need to control on both the direction it would be easy to use `grid` layout. Flex is mainly used to use if you want to change the content in one direction either in `row` or `column`.

Comment: Ok, right. I am new to front-end so I am still learning how to deal with these concepts. Thank you very much for your willingness and help, without a doubt it was very useful